# Text file not updating right away when using TextWriter

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `TextWriter` to write serial data coming every 100ms on a text file. But the text file is not updated right away. Sometimes it takes few seconds and sometimes a minute for the written text to be shown on the .txt file. How can i fix that?

```
   TextWriter tw;

    tw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path + "\\" + currentSubdirName + "\\" + currentFileName, FileMode.CreateNew));
    tw.Write(text);
```

Comment: Add: `tw.Flush()`, that will flush the buffers to disk.

Comment: i should call `tw.Flush()` after `tw.Write(text);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call flush for any buffered data to be written to the file immediately

```
 TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path + "\\" + currentSubdirName + "\\" + currentFileName, FileMode.CreateNew));
 tw.Write(text);
 tw.Flush();
 tw.Dispose();
```

or alternatively you can using TextWriter in a using statement which will flush all the buffered data on TextWriter.Dispose, This way you need not to handle Writer.Dispose

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path + "\\" + currentSubdirName + "\\" + currentFileName, FileMode.CreateNew));)
{
    tw.Write("test");
}
```

Comment: Also, disposing the writer (as you have shown here) will cause the data to be flushed implicitly.

Comment: `tw.Flush();` is redundant since `TextWriter.Dispose` will flush all the cache

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko agreed. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The data is only written when the relevant buffers are filled. You can force a flush using `tw.Flush()`, which will push the (partial) data from the `TextWriter` to the `FileStream`.

Note that this may have a significant impact on performance, though. Caching and buffering are quite important, since disks are just so much slower than RAM (and RAM is much slower than the CPU). Make sure the cost is worth the benefits, and consider only flushing once in a while anyway.